# How can I have an interface/abstract class function return type same as the implementer?

Tags: typescript, oop, typescript-typings

I want to have an interface or abstract class that specifies a function, and I want that function to return the same type as the implementation of that abstract class/interface. Take the following example:

```
interface XY {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

abstract class Movable {
    abstract getPosition(): XY;
    abstract translate(v: XY): RETURN_TYPE;

    moveTo(p: XY): RETURN_TYPE {
      const current = this.getPosition();
      const v: XY = {
        x: p.x - current.x,
        y: p.y - current.y
      };

      return this.translate(p);
    }
}

class Point extends Movable implements XY {
    x: number;
    y: number;

    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
      super()
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }

    getPosition(): XY {
      return this;
    }

    translate(v: XY): Point {
      return new Point(
        this.x + v.x,
        this.y + v.y
      );
    }
}

const p1 = new Point(5, 4);
const p2 = p1.moveTo({x: 0, y: 0}); // I want the type of p2 to be Point.
```

By sub-classing Movable, I know that I can call the .moveTo method. However, I want .moveTo to return the same type as the subclass. In this example, p2 should also be a Point, and in fact we know that it is because Point.translate returns another Point. And the implementation of Movable.moveTo returns the same type as .translate.

The way I see it, I have a few options.

#### 1. Return type is Movable.

This gives me the same problem I just stated, I lose information about the subclassed type when I call .moveTo, I know that p1.moveTo returns another object that is Movable, but I don't know that it is a Point.

This has been an issue for me because I will take an array of Movable, filter the list down to one subclass (using instanceof), map the .translate method, then I no longer know that my array is of the type of that subclass.

#### 2. Make Movable Generic.

Up until now, this is what I have been doing. I have every subclass of Movable tell Movable what the return type should be. I can keep doing things like this, but it feels like I'm doing something awkward or wrong.

```
abstract class Movable<T> {
    abstract translate(v: XY): T;
    ...
}

class Point extends Movable<Point> {
    ...
}
```

#### 3. Get rid of the abstract class.

I could get rid of the abstract class, I could make Movable an interface, then get rid of the implementation of moveTo. I would set the return type of Movable.translate to Movable, and then Point.translate to Point. Point would then be responsible for implementing moveTo.

I know implementation inheritance is bad, so this isn't a terrible idea, but in my codebase I really only have one or two functions that I inherit. I only have to test translate and getPosition in my subclasses, and I know moveTo will work on all of them, so in my mind this is a perfect use case for implementation inheritance. This makes a lot of sense to me, because some of my other subclasses are like Line, Polygon, etc.

Right now I am leaning towards #2 or #3, any insight or wisdom would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, you can use [`this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) as the type for the return values of the methods, but that makes another problem appear: the `translate` implementation could be called from a `Point` subclass which would make the types incompatible. Unfortunately, there is no such thing as a `final class` in TypeScript.

```
abstract class Movable {
    abstract getPosition(): XY;
    abstract translate(v: XY): this;

    moveTo(p: XY): this {
      const current = this.getPosition();
      const v: XY = {
        x: p.x - current.x,
        y: p.y - current.y
      };

      return this.translate(p);
    }
}
```

I guess the better solution to your problem is #2. Repeating `Point` in its own declaration is not so much of a pain.